# Exploratory data analysis for discrete data

Tags: data-visualization, logit, probit, exploratory-data-analysis

I am using a probit and a logit model for obtaining the choice probabilities of some data. What kind of plots can be useful to conduct a exploratory data analysis for these data?

Here is the simulated data:

```
set.seed(1)
x.first <- rbinom(1000,1,0.5)
x.second <- rbinom(1000,1,0.5)
y <- rbinom(1000,1,0.5)
delta.x <- x.first-x.second
```

and my models are

```
 logit(p) <- delta.x beta

 phi^{-1}(p) <- delta.x beta
```

where phi^{-1} is the inverse of the standard normal distribution `cdf`and beta is the regression coefficients.

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure why your independent variable is the difference between two binomials, but your delta.x takes three values: -1, 0 and 1. Thus, both your DV and your IV are categorical.

One good graphic for such data is the mosaic plot. One implementation is in the `vcd` package.  Add to your code, e.g.,

```
library(vcd)
mosaic(y~delta.x)
```

for a very basic version.

Comment: There are two options for people to choose from: first and second which are represented by x.first and x.second. What I am interested in is that I want to obtain the probability of choosing the first over second. Therefore, I use the difference matrix. What would you suggest in my situation?

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean by "first over second" but there isn't anything wrong with your dependent variable, I just wasn't sure why you had picked it.

Comment: The interest here is to estimate the choice probabilities by using either a logit or probit model. People are given two options and they choose one. So, the aim is to estimate the probability that the first option is chosen.